# How to update the property value within same array object when one of property id same using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, react-select

For the array of objects `arrobj` , passing a parameter called `paramid`.

if the `arrobj` property

`id` has same value as `paramid`, then update the property `price` to `null`

and `oldValue` (refers to price value before set to null) of object should be updated to

remaining objects only for `oldvalue` is greater than `price` price.

Update in the format

like oldvalue, oldvalue+1, oldvalue+2...  how to achieve this using javascript.

```
example 1

let paramid = 25
const arrobj = [
  { id: 10, price: null },
  { id: 12, price: 1 },
  { id: 14, price: 2 },
  { id: 25, price: 3 }, 
  { id: 23, price: 4 },
  { id: 43, price: 5 },

];
// arrobj id is same as paramid, `price` becomes null for `id` 25 and its oldvalue price `3` moves to next object id `23`(oldvalue), then to id `43` price (oldvalue+1)
Expected Output:
 [
  { id: 10, price: null },
  { id: 12, price: 1 },
  { id: 14, price: 2 },
  { id: 25, price: null }, 
  { id: 23, price: 3 },
  { id: 43, price: 4 },

];

example 2
let paramid = 43
const arrobj = [
  { id: 10, price: null },
  { id: 13, price: 1 },
  { id: 14, price: 2 },
  { id: 25, price: 5 }, 
  { id: 23, price: 6 },
  { id: 43, price: 4 },
  { id: 28, price: 7 }
];

// arrobj id is same as paramid, `price` becomes null for `id` 43 and its oldvalue price `4` moves to next object id `25`, then to id `23`  

Expected Output:
 [
  { id: 10, price: null },
  { id: 12, price: 1 },
  { id: 14, price: 2 },
  { id: 25, price: 4 }, 
  { id: 23, price: 5 },
  { id: 43, price: null },
  { id: 28, price: 6 }

];
```

// Note: price is always updated to next consecutive price value.

```
Tried
const getSameId =  arrobj(e=>e.id === paramid);

let oldValue = getSameId.price;

for (let item of arrobj) {
  const index = arrobj.index(item)
  if(item.id === paramid) {
   ...item,
   price: null 
  }
  if(item.id !== paramid && oldValue > item.price) {
   ...item,
   price: oldValue + 1 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 3 different issues:

To get an item matching a condition the syntax is actually `arrayObj.find(e => e.id === paramid`). Note that only the first value matching the criteria will be returned, and that the returned value is `undefined` if no value matching the criteria is found.
(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

And the syntax to get the index of an item is `arrobj.indexOf(item)`.
(See documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Or you could merge these 2 steps by doing `arrayObj.findIndex(e => e.id === paramid)`, and then update the values using that index.

The last issue is the way you get the new value for subsequent items: you're adding 1 to their current price, instead of getting the value from a previous item.

```js
const sameIdIndex = arrObj.findIndex((item) => item.id === paramid);

const updatedArray = arrObj.map((item, index) => {
  if (index === sameIdIndex) {
    return { ...item, price: null };
  }
  if (index > sameIdIndex) {
    const indexToGetFrom = sameIdIndex + (index - sameIdIndex) - 1;
    return { ...item, price: arrObj[indexToGetFrom].price };
  }
  return item;
});
```

(you can still do that with a `for`, I just use `Array.map()` because I personally prefer it)

Comment: Thanks , but logic is not working for this``` let paramid = 28
const arrObj = [
  { id: 10, price: null }, 
  { id: 13, price: 1 }, 
  { id: 14, price: 2 },
  { id: 25, price: 5 },
  { id: 23, price: 8 },
  { id: 43, price: 7 },
  { id: 28, price: 6 } 
];
```

Comment: Added the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/ny4mcr7q/ please help

Comment: It's like should I call it recursively ? any idea how to achieve this

Comment: No, you just call it once. Your fiddle seems to be working, what's the issue?